# Docker Build Platform linux/amd64 Image on Apple M1 Max: Package Not Availble

Tags: docker, x86-64, apple-m1, apt, apt-get

I'm using the same Dockerfile to build 2 different images, the only difference is one is build with `--platform linux/amd64`

With the one using platform linux/amd64
When I run
`apt-get install python3` or any package

I get

`Package python3 is not available, but is referred to by another package.`

`This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or #7 0.615 is only available from another source`

This basically happened for every package I was trying to install.

I have done apt-get update & upgrade.

Comment: can you share the dockerfile?